# Extract with conditions a list of id from a table of coupled records with mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql `table` with couples of records with the following columns:

```
id,
name,
surname,
place
```

Example:

```
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+
| id | name   | surname   | place        |
+----+--------+-----------+--------------+
|  1 | arya   | stark     | unknown      |
|  2 | aria   | stark     | unknown      |
|  3 | john   | snow      | winterfell   |
|  4 | jonh   | snow      | unknown      |
|  5 | tyrion | lannister | unknown      |
|  6 | tirion | lannister | kingslanding |
```

Surname are always matching in couple but names can be different.
Place can be "unknown" or have a value. Now I need to extract a list of id to identify the oldest record. 
I need to identify those records that have `place` fields set to `unknown` and the other record of couple set to something else.
In the example i want to extract id 4 and 5. Any ideas?

Comment: Join the table with itself and test the condition of the `place` columns between the two records.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: That’s simply not true